# Dúvida sobre filtro com datas

Tags: sql, pl-sql, oracle10g

Sou iniciante no SQL, e estou trabalhando em um projeto no Oracle. Empaquei numa situação que teoricamente seria simples de resolver, mas que não obtenho sucesso. Conseguem me ajudar?

Abaixo segue o código que estou tentando aplicar, tudo está funcionando menos o filtro da data. O que estou fazendo de errado? E qual a sugestão de correção? Preciso das datas maiores que 21/01/2020.

```
Select BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO.HISO_CD_OBJETO,
         BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO.HISO_CD_TIPO_OBJETO_TEXT_LONGO,
         BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO.HISO_DT_MODIFICACAO_STATUS
  from BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO
  where BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO.HISO_CD_OBJETO = 'OR002022477553'
  and BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO.HISO_DT_MODIFICACAO_STATUS > '21-01-2020'
  order by BIIN.HISTORICO_STATUS_OBJETO.HISO_DT_MODIFICACAO_STATUS asc
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente a data assim: '2020-01-21'. Veja a necessidade de fazer um `cast`.

Comment: Force o formato to_date('21/01 /2020','DD/MM/YYYY') para maiores detalhes https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780